# AlertDialog: Why can't I show Message and List together?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Does anybody know why the `AlertDialog` doesn't show the list of items when I add a Message with `.setMessage()`?
The negative and positive buttons will be shown, but not the list.
When I delete the line with `.setMessage()` everything works.

This is my code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder myAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getActivity());
myAlertDialog.setTitle("Options");
myAlertDialog.setMessage("Choose a color.");

CharSequence[] items = {"RED", "BLUE", "GREEN" };

myAlertDialog.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // do stuff
    }
});

myAlertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
       // do stuff
    }
});

myAlertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
       // do stuff
    }
});

myAlertDialog.create();
myAlertDialog.show();
```

Comment: Where you have added the list items ?

Comment: Why don't you put only "myAlertDialog.setTitle("Choose a color");" ?

Comment: @Alex Feh Check out my answer.

Comment: @GrIsHu The List is in the var "items" as an CharSequence[] as you can see in line 5 of the code. The items are added in the first parameter of .setSingleChouceItems() in line 7.

Comment: @JaAd This code only shows an example, in my code it would be great if i could use both.

Comment: @JaAd yes, i get your point here. But i have an layout that requires this look, i know stupid. But if it doesn't work i have to live with it.
The most thing that bothered me with this problem was that i wasted a lot of time not knowing that the .setMessage() was the problem why the list wasn't shown. Is there an convention or something for that?

Comment: @AlexFeh the only think you can do is a custom Dialog with a title, a text (in your case "Choose a color.") and a list below the text. By the way, giacomino's answer is good and if you don't want to loose more time, replace "Options" with "Choose a color." ;-) .

Answer (score 16):

From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html),

> Because the list appears in the dialog's content area, the dialog cannot show both a message and a list and you should set a title for the dialog with setTitle().

The `setMessage()` and `setSingleChoiceItems()` are therefore mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 11):

`AlertDialog` creates its content dynamically by checking if `mMessage` that you set via `setMessage()` is `null`. If `mMessage` is **NOT** `null` (that means you have called `setMessage()` method), then it setups its content for **ONLY** `TextView` to show message and **skips** `listview` setup. If you haven't called `setMessage()`, then it removes `TextView` and then setups for `listview`.

## Solution

So, to show both message and list in dialog, I suggest you to use below solution which setups custom view for AlertDialog.

```
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Dialog title");

    final List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();

    items.add("Item 1");
    items.add("Item 2");
    items.add("Item 3");

    final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapterItems = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, items);

    View content = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_msg_dialog, null);

    //this is the TextView that displays your message
    TextView tvMessage = content.findViewById(R.id.tv_msg);

    tvMessage.setText("Dialog message!!!");

    //this is the ListView that lists your items
    final ListView lvItems = content.findViewById(R.id.lv_items);
    lvItems.setAdapter(arrayAdapterItems);
    lvItems.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    builder.setView(content);
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //do something
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    items.get(lvItems.getCheckedItemPosition()),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

    lvItems.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //when you need to act on itemClick
        }
    });


    dialog.show();
```

And this is `list_msg_dialog.xml` layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="3dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_msg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:text="some text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItem"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv_items"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@null" /></LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a little tricky, but you can use `myAlertDialog.setCustomTitle(myTextView)` and custom yout textView as title and text with HTML format.

```
TextView textView = new TextView(context);
textView.setText("YourTitle\n\n Your body");
myAlertDialog.setCustomTitle(textView);
```

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for!

Comment: thank you, but html <h1> not working here.

Answer (score -2):

Try to set the items in your alertdialog as below:

```
  AlertDialog.Builder myAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getActivity());
  myAlertDialog.setTitle("Options");
  myAlertDialog.setMessage("Choose a color.");
  myAlertDialog.getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
 CharSequence[] items = {"RED","BLUE","GREEN"};

 myAlertDialog.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

 public void onClick(DialogInterface d, int choice) {

   }
  });
     ............
   myAlertDialog.create();
 myAlertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score -2):

You can make your alert dialog with list using the following method:

```
AlertDialog.Builder myAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getActivity());
myAlertDialog.setTitle("Options");
myAlertDialog.setMessage("Choose a color.");

List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();   
items.add("RED");
items.add("BLUE");
items.add("GREEN");

final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapterItems = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, items);

myAlertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
       // do stuff
    }
});
myAlertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
       // do stuff
    }
});

myAlertDialog.setAdapter(arrayAdapterItems,
new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        //do what you want
    }
});
myAlertDialog.show();
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: At the line myAlertDialog.setAdapter() i get an error that the var items has to be an ListAdapter and not a List<String>.
Did i do something wrong? I just copied your code.

Comment: No, sry it was my mistake. You were getting error because it was trying to set the List instead the ListAdapter, that I forgot to create. I editted my answer, now it should works!

Comment: Yes, now the code works.
But unfortunately i have to remove .setMessage() to see the List.
But thank you, i like the way with the adapter!

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, as above the message and items are mutually exclusive.